# Angular 2 issue with my subscription

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

My **app.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { MainService } from './main.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private logsub: Subscription;
    private checking: string;
    constructor(private af: AngularFire, private mainService: MainService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.logsub = this.mainService.userThere$.subscribe(isUser => {
            if (isUser){
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                    if (user){
                        this.mainService.userLogged(true);
                        alert("True");
                    }
                    else {
                        this.mainService.userLogged(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        if (this.mainService.userLogged){alert("Fish");}
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.logsub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

My **main.services**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class MainService {
    private userThere = new Subject<boolean>();
    userThere$ = this.userThere.asObservable();

    userLogged(isUser: boolean){
        this.userThere.next(isUser);
    }
}
```

What I am not understanding here is this. I have a user authorization code. If there is a user, I will get back an `alert("True")`. And I also set my `userLogged` subscription true.

When I load my page, I can confirm that there is no user. I do not get the `alert("True");`. However, below this I have included a test code `if (this.mainService.userLogged){alert("Fish");}`.

Despite there being no user, I am still being alerted of Fish.

Comment: Of course `this.mainService.userLogged` will be truthy, as the function `userLogged` is defined

Comment: So how might I reformat my if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert` is being called as in the `if` block, you are checking whether the method `userLogged` exists on the service `mainService`

`if (this.mainService.userLogged){alert("Fish")`;}

As the `mainService` is injected into your component( that is,  instantiated and passed into the constructor of your component by the angular injector ), it will have all the methods you define in it. *typescript classes* are ultimately *javascript constructor functions* which when instantiated give you *javascript objects*. Those objects can have functions as properties, which as you may be aware are first class objects in JS.

So above in the if block when you check for `this.mainService.userLogged` you are getting a **truthy** value, as `userLogged` is defined in `mainService`. Hence it is going into the `if` block and `alert` is being fired.

EDIT :

Based on the comments what I gather is that you want to be able to write additional logic when user info reaches you via the `mainService.userThere$` observer stream . We can have multiple call backs for a single observer stream. That is all of the call backs you register with the observer stream will be called when the observer source is triggered. So you can do this    :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.logsub = this.mainService.userThere$.subscribe(isUser => {
        if (isUser){
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if (user){
                    //this.mainService.userLogged(true);
                    alert("True");
                    // no need to set userLogged true or false again 
                }
                else {
                    //this.mainService.userLogged(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });

//if (this.mainService.userLogged){alert("Fish");}
// instead of above do this
this.mainService.userThere$.subscribe( isUser => {
    alert("Fish");
    // We can attach as many functions as we want to the
    // observer stream. So all you have to do is simply pass
    // userThere$ observer stream in any component you want to
    // write the additional logic
})



 }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah. In retrospect that makes sense. So how would I format my `if statement`? Changing it to `this.mainService.userLogged = true` doesn't do it.

Comment: Okay let me try to understand what you want to do here. basically you want to fire an alert when the user is present . Am I correct ?

Comment: What I want is to set up a service that can get fired from any component as an if condition. So if `userLogged` then allow my component (be it app or whatever) to do `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Only question I have now, is say if I have a function like `testRun(){ my content here }`. Would I have to subscribe again inside the function?

Comment: Yes , you will have to simply pass testRun as a call back to the subscribe. subscribe(testRun)